# Java - How to print from 0 to z without !@#$%^&*()?><":{}| letters, only alphabet and numbers

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to get a txt file with only the alphabet and numbers writted.
In the txt file there are also the non alphabet characters.

```java
public class WordChanger2 {

    static int input = 2; /// input line length

    public static ArrayList<Character> str; /// a list containing characters.
    public static PrintWriter output; 
    public void saveToFile(int size,int lineSize){    

        if(size == lineSize){
            String s = "";
            for (Character str1 : str) {
                s+=str1;
            }
            output.println(s);
            return;
        }
        for(char i = '0';i<='z';i++){ //from number 0 to lower z
            str.add(i);
            saveToFile(size+1,lineSize);
            str.remove(str.size()-1);
            System.out.println(str); //showing the Characters on console
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int lineSize = input;
        output = new PrintWriter("E:\\output.txt");  /// file path
        str = new ArrayList<Character>();

        WordChanger2 c =  new WordChanger2();
        c.saveToFile(0 ,lineSize);
        output.close();
        System.out.println("Done! check the Txt file on your E: drive");
    }
}
```

Trying to get this:

> ```
> 00
> 01
> 02
> 03
> 04
> 05
> 06
> 07
> 08
> 09
> 0A
> 0B
> 0C
> 0D
> 0E
> 0F
> 0G
> 0H
> 0I
> 0J
> 0K
> 0L
> 0M
> 0N
> 0O
> 0P
> 0Q
> 0R
> 0S
> 0T
> 0U
> 0V
> 0W
> 0X
> 0Y
> 0Z
> 0a
> 0b
> 0c
> 0d
> 0e
> 0f
> 0g
> 0h
> 0i
> 0j
> 0k
> 0l
> 0m
> 0n
> 0o
> 0p
> 0q
> 0r
> 0s
> 0t
> 0u
> 0v
> 0w
> 0x
> 0y
> 0z
> ```

Comment: loop from `0`to `9`, then from `A`to`Z`, then from `a`to`z`? I don't see the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

Use [`Character#IsLetterOrDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) method in the `for`loop
It's quite explicit.

```
for(char i = '0';i<='z';i++){ //from number 0 to lower z
    if (Character.IsLetterOrDigit(i) {
        str.add(i);
        saveToFile(size+1,lineSize);
        str.remove(str.size()-1);
        System.out.println(str); //showing the Characters on console
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2:

Use more loops:

```
for(char i = '0';i<='9';i++){ //from number 0 to 9
    //do something
}
for(char i = 'A';i<='Z';i++){ //from letter A to Z
    //do something
}
for(char i = 'a';i<='z';i++){ //from letter a to z
    //do something
}
```

This could be improved to avoid to much code duplication

#### Solution 3: (credits for Andy Turner)

Create a String containing each letters and digits in the correct order and loop on this string to build the ouptut

```
String table = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (int i=0; i<table.size(); i++) {
    str.add(table.charAt(i));
    ...
}
```

> **Side note:**
>   I think using recursive call to do what you are trying to is a bit overkill. Why not build a single string, appending characters in the loop and when the loop ends, write it where ever you want?

Comment: Oh okey, Thank you!

Comment: Another solution with one loop: create a string `"0123456789ABCD...Zabcd...z"`, and iterate through character-by-character.